# IONIC 3 BarcodeScanner crashes android build

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic3, barcode-scanner

I get the error when build ionic project on android platform:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

  > Could not find :barcodescanner:.
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository//barcodescanner//barcodescanner-.pom
  >     file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository//barcodescanner//barcodescanner-.aar
  >     file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository//barcodescanner//barcodescanner-.pom
  >     file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository//barcodescanner//barcodescanner-.aar
  >     file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository//barcodescanner//barcodescanner-.pom
  >     file:/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository//barcodescanner//barcodescanner-.aar
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com//barcodescanner//barcodescanner-.pom
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com//barcodescanner//barcodescanner-.aar
  >     https://maven.google.com//barcodescanner//barcodescanner-.pom
  >     https://maven.google.com//barcodescanner//barcodescanner-.aar
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2//barcodescanner//barcodescanner-.pom
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2//barcodescanner//barcodescanner-.aar
  >     file:/Users/user/developer/project/platforms/android/app/libs/barcodescanner-.aar
  >     file:/Users/user/developer/project/platforms/android/app/libs/barcodescanner.aar
  >   Required by:
  >     project :app

this is my ionic enviroment:

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
ios-sim           : 5.0.1 
Node              : v8.9.3
npm               : 5.6.0 
OS                : macOS High Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

I created the new and blank ionic project and added the native barcodescanner plugin following the commands:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/barcode-scanner
```

The Android SDK build tools was updated in 27.0.3 version

anybody for help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is caused by an incompatibility between cordova-android 7 and the plugin. Somebody already [reported it](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/589) and I [fixed it](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/pull/592) yesterday.

You will have to wait until those changes are released as a new version (probably 7.0.2), or install the plugin from the github url

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner`

Comment: thanks for reply and share the plugin information, but the install plugin from the github not works. I did the downgrade cordova android plugin to version 6.4.0 and work now.

Comment: Did you remove the plugin first? Did you get the same error message after using the github url?

Comment: yes! I removed the plugin first, but the install from github throws an error.  CordovaError: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner via registry.

Comment: Any news on this? cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
(node:3976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL. Thanks!

Comment: I think that’s a bug in cordova, try installing from npm

Comment: my problem is :
Element uses-feature#android.hardware.camera at AndroidManifest.xml:70:5-84 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:54:5-60

Comment: This is still happening with plugin  7.1.2 on android platform 7.1.4.

Comment: I doubt it's the same problem, please, report it at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues so it can be tracked and fixed. Also, latest plugin is 8.0.1